# R barplot with bin division

Tags: r, bar-chart

I need to make a bar graph where the data is divided into bins.

My data looks like this:

```
1.0 5
1.2 4
2.4 1
4.3 6
5.2 10
```

Then on the X axis I want to have the value of time, like: [1-4), [4-5), etc. (depending on the data in the csv file).

On the Y axis I want to have a number of occurrences, like 10, 16, etc.

I have written this R code:

```
dataset <- read.csv("/Users/MNeptune/Documents/workspace R/BarPlot/times.csv")
dataset <- data.matrix(dataset, rownames.force = NA)
time <- dataset[,1]
occurence <- dataset[,2]
min <- min(time);
max <- max(time);

# Creo i bin
Groups <- cut(x = time, breaks = seq(from = min, to = max, by = 2))
Groups <- data.matrix(Groups, rownames.force = NA)

# Raggruppo i dati nei bin
Bygroup = tapply(occurence, Groups, sum)

# Faccio il plot dei bin
barplot(height = Bygroup, xlab = "time", ylab = "occurence")
```

But the code does not bin the data correctly (wrong number and not in just order). Where is the problem?

**Edit1:**

Thanks of eipi10 I have obtain this (bin lenght of 0.01):

[image: Time/Occurence graph with bin lenght of 0.01]

Now the problem is how to read the X axis label, because I need to read the valure of local minima.

How i can put a "scale bar" like Y axis ?

Ok i can't put the exact value of all bin, but at least one everey 0.5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see what's going wrong if you do the following:

```
seq(from=1.0, to=5.2, by=2)
[1] 1 3 5

cut(c(1.0,1.2,2.4,4.3,5.2), breaks=seq(from=1.0, to=5.2, by=2))
[1] <NA>  (1,3] (1,3] (3,5] <NA> 
Levels: (1,3] (3,5]
```

In other words, `seq` stops at the highest value less than 5.2, which is 5, so you miss the row with `time`=5.2. In addition, `cut`, by default, excludes the low end of the value range, so you miss that as well when you use the lowest value of `time` as the low end of the `cut` range.

Here's a reworking of your code to get the plot you're looking for:

```
dat=read.table(text="time occurence
1.0 5
1.2 4
2.4 1
4.3 6
5.2 10", header=TRUE)

# Creo i bin
dat$Groups <- cut(x=dat$time, breaks=seq(from=0, to=ceiling(max(dat$time)), by = 2))

# Raggruppo i dati nei bin
Bygroup = tapply(dat$occurence, dat$Groups, sum)

# Faccio il plot dei bin
barplot(height = Bygroup, xlab = "time", ylab = "occurence")
```

[image]

If you want different breaks, you can of course adjust the `breaks` argument of `cut`. In particular, note the `right` argument to `cut`, which allows you to choose whether you want the break intervals to be closed on the left or the right. `right=TRUE` is the default, which is why the first row of your data was excluded from `Groups` in your original code.

**UPDATE**: To answer your follow-up question, you can find the bin of the minimum value of `Bygroup` as follows:

```
names(Bygroup)[which.min(Bygroup)]
[1] "(2,4]"
```

If you want to rank the `Bygroup` values to find the lowest, next lowest, etc. you can use `rank`, which returns the rank of each value:

```
rank(Bygroup)
(0,2] (2,4] (4,6] 
    2     1     3
```